# Custom empires / kingdoms and de jure

Tags: crusader-kings-2

With the Charlemagne expansion you can form your own kingdoms and eventually empires if you have enough territory, titles and prestige to do it. So I founded my own kingdom and later my own empire, but I, of course, have no de jure territory for either (some wiki's suggest that whatever you hold at the time becomes de jure, but that doesn't seem to be the case). Can territory eventually drift into my custom empire? And related, it seems like since I have no de jure territory, my crown laws apply to absolutely nobody. I set my crown authority to medium to stop my vassals fighting among themselves, but it seems to make no difference. They seem to be working on the crown laws of the kingdoms they belong to instead of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a custom kingdom or empire, any territory you control that could drift into it will immediately become a de jure part of it. This means that any duchies you completely control will become part of a new kingdom and any kingdoms you completely control will become part of a new empire.

Once you have a custom kingdom or empire, duchies or kingdoms respectively can drift into it. This happens in the same way as with any other kingdom or empire.

Comment: Then something is wrong. I have nothing de jure in my empire. If I look at the empire screen it a "titular" empire with no de jure possessions. I wonder if it might be related to me switching primary titles right before I created my empire (I thought empire of Jerusalem sounded better than empire of <random county that my kingdom was named after>.

Comment: @Wjousts Ah, that explains it. The Kingdom of Jerusalem and the duchies in it cannot De Jure drift. It's something to do with messing up the crusade priorities.

Comment: Crap. So you're telling me the Empire of Jerusalem inherited the properties of the Kingdom (no drift). Well that was an unexpected pitfall.

Comment: @wjousts I don't think it would have necessarily inherited the no drift property but you wouldn't be able to de jure drift the Kingdom of Jerusalem into it.

Comment: But I had a bunch of territory, and other titles (including kingdom level titles) when I created my empire and nothing got included as de jure in my new empire. I'm wondering if it didn't look at my primary title (which was king of Jerusalem) and look at what might be drifting into it at the time I created my empire and decided nothing was drifting. I feel like I might have just falling into an edge case trap here. Not a huge deal because I'm close to taking a real empire anyway.

Comment: Did you control all the territory in those kingdoms?